# Prolonging time after submit Button clicked Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a test case for Selenium webdriver in which i want to test if the Submit Button is disabled after clicking it. The pb is that after clicking can't assert if button isEnabled
because i got the Element not found error. (tried with wait after click but got the same error) 
    Is there a way to prolong the action after clicking a button in order still to have that element on the page?

```
  WebElement btn=webdriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='submitButton']"));

  btn.click(); 

  assertFalse(btn.isEnabled());
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a method which will check whether element is present on the page or not and return true or false based on the findings. Example is written below:

```
public boolean isElementPresent(WebDriver driver, By by){

   try{

     driver.findElement(by);
     return true;

   }

   catch(NoSuchElementException noSuchElementException){
     return false;
   }


}
```

Now, from your main code call the above method to see whether element is present on the page or not. Example is written below:

```
By locatorSubmitButton = By.xpath(".//*[@id='submitButton']");
WebElement btn=webdriver.findElement(locatorSubmitButton );
btn.click();
assertFalse(isElementPresent(webdriver, locatorSubmitButton));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thnks, it doesn't work. I used  webdriver().navigate().back() and the button is in the state after pressing it.

Comment: Please explain the reason for using `webdriver().navigate().back()` logic?

Comment: it seams that the browser keeps the last state of a page (where my btn is disabled..so i was able to test the btn). So when i go back i have the page with the btn disabled. can't explain exactly (maybe with cookie or....has to do)

Comment: You mean when you submit the page by clicking, you are directed to another page and you want to go back to check if the button is disabled? Anyway, even if you are not redirected to another page, but the page is simply reloaded, you have lost your reference for the webElement, meaning you have to look it up again by using driver.findElement()

Comment: oh! is it the case? Thanks Erki for nice explanation. @Eli: Please respond back if this is the case. If yes, we have to use `btn=webdriver.findElement(locatorSubmitButton );` again after click operation is done.